# Display output is columns based on filter criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display data is columns/subcolumns based on certain filter criteria using case when statement but not getting required output.

data:

```
ID   ID2  Country  Type
1    001   US       A
1    009   US       A
2    002   AU       B
3    003   CA       A
3    005   CA       A
4    007   US       B
5    001   FR       B
6    003   US       B
7    002   US       A
8    004   NZ       A
```

based on my current case statement, here is how my output looks:

```
Type    Country    Count
B        Other       2
B        US          1
B        Subtotal    3
A        Other       4 
A        US          3
A        Subtotal    7
Total                10
```

I want to display the following format, bonus if I can get the subtotal/totals:

```
  Type-A       Type-B
US    Other    US    Other
3      4        1    2
```

I also need  Subtotals, and Grandtotals, but these need to be calculated separately.
SubTotal: 7      SubTotal: 3
    Grand Total: 10

Comment: which SQL are you using? My SQL, SQL Server?

Comment: I use Oracle sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like this

```
select
    sum(case when Type = 'A' and Country = 'US' then 1 else 0 end) as US_TYPE_A,
    sum(case when Type = 'A' and Country != 'US' then 1 else 0 end) as Other_TYPE_A,
    sum(case when Type = 'B' and Country = 'US' then 1 else 0 end) as US_TYPE_B,
    sum(case when Type = 'B' and Country != 'US' then 1 else 0 end) as Other_TYPE_B
from myTable
```

Comment: ok, is there a way to get subtotals/grand total in this format?

Comment: @Skn which format, please update your expected answer?

Comment: I have updated it, to see if the subtotal and grand total can be displayed.

Comment: You need to add columns for your expected result.

Comment: I am not sure how it will be displayed, can you please clarify which columns you are referring to?